# Conceptual question on Java Socket Input/Output streams

Tags: java, sockets

Does anyone know why in the Java `Socket` class, `getInputStream` reads bytes from the socket, while `getOutputStream` writes bytes to the socket? Intuitively I feel like reading should be an output stream, while writing should be an input stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The streams are named from *your* perspective. An input stream is a place where data is input to your program, and an output stream is a place where your program outputs data to.

No different from `FileIn-`/`OutputStream`, or `System.in`/`out`.

Even `java.lang.Process` is named this way (confusingly) - the `getOutputStream` method returns the other process's *input* stream, which you can write data to.